# samba openldap user file premissions

Tags: linux, permissions, centos6, samba, openldap

we are testing openldap server with samba3 backend for a new domain in our company.
How can we implement users with different permissions on home directory.
we want some users to have full access to save data on desktop and home directory while others won't be able to save or modify any data.

We are planning to replace all windows machines from the environment with Centos 6 including servers and workstations.

Any suggestion for implementation using open source technologies?

Answer (score 1):

This question makes it sound like you are just starting to implement Samba3.  If that's the case, *don't* use version 3, it's been discontinued, there's no more work being done on it.

If you use Samba4, you can implement it as a Microsoft-compatible AD domain and get all the usual Windows permissions - you can easily set permissions on network or local drives.

Comment: We are still in testing phase and we did consider Samba4 but I am unable to find step by step guide to implement Domain Controller with GUI on Samba4 like phpldapadmin. Links or references will be really very helpful.

Comment: This answer has some information on Samba4 and links to the samba.org wiki, which is the best place to look for documentation.  http://serverfault.com/questions/760059/opensource-alternative-to-ms-active-directory

Comment: I believe Samba4 may solve the problems but the end users are not expert in Unix/Linux environments, so we need a GUI based solution for user creation and management. Also I am new to installing and configuring Domain Controller in Unix/Linux environment, for end to end configuration, I need some reference blog or posts that explains the setup process step by step. I have been reading wiki.samba.org but the information provided is not sufficient to install and configure. I even googled out for solutions but unable to find full documentation for setup process.

Comment: As that other answer says, you administer Samba4 using the same Windows tools you would for Windows Server.

Comment: We are planning the environment without dependency on windows systems, to save on license costs. 
Also Samba4 is under development as of now, and it supports LDAP and openldap is not supported. I am unable to find step by step instructions to deploy my domain from any blog or post. Instructions from wiki.samba.org is not enough to deploy Domain end to end.
The phpldapadmin tool supports 4.0.0_alpha7 version 
http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/LDAP_Servers